# In swift I need to reposition the cursor in a textfield if the user enters data that does not conform to preset criterion

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

If a user enters data  in a textfield that does not conform to some criterion such as only numeric data to be entered I want to clear that field and position the cursor in that textfield so that user  will be forced to make a correct entry.

Comment: Great. What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: I have tried the becomeFirstResponder but it does not take the cursor back to the textfield i.e. I can't find a method of forcing an correct entry in a textfield.

Answer (score 0):

VerifyInput[tagCas].becomeFirstResponder()
sorry  I was being dim.